# Macro to fill cell based on value of a different cell

Tags: excel, vba

Have looked for this but have never fully understood all the answers so thought I'd post.

I have a sheet with 5000+ rows of information with 3 columns and need a way to quickly process the sheet based on the value of column 3.

I am having trouble even starting this. Sorry I'm a noob when it comes to Excel Macros and VBA.

I have a list of people and I want to assign a manager based on the office the user belongs to. It's seperated into the following columns:

```
firstname | surname | officeN
```

If the user belongs to `{office1, office3, office7}` then `Manager1` will be responsible for them.

If the user belongs to `{office2, office4, office5}` then `Manager2` will be responsible for them and so on.

I would like it if a 4th column would then be filled with the ManagerN based on the office the user belongs to so it would result in:

```
firstname | surname | officeN | ManagerN
```

Is this possible to do with an Excel Macro? Sorry I know there are similar questions out there, I'm just finding it hard to understand them or apply sections to my situation.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a macro for this. Somewhere in your workbook put all your office names in a column and on the next column put the corresponding manager. Now in your sheet where you want to match the user with his manager, simply use VLOOKUP like this:

`=VLOOKUP(C1, MappingSheet!A:B, 2, 0)`

Where `C1` is the first cell containing the office number, `MappingSheet!A:B` is where you have stored the offices and managers.